# Implement custom java swing component into test application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, testing, custom-component

I have developed a custom swing component that is used to zoom in and out of an image. This has been a very difficult task for me considering I am very new to Java and Swing. From what I can tell I have implemented my classes correctly however I cannot seem to figure out how to run my component in a test application.

//AbstractZoomModel

```
package component;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel;

public abstract class AbstractZoomModel extends DefaultBoundedRangeModel implements ZoomModel {

public AbstractZoomModel() {
    super(100, 0, 0, 200);
}

@Override
public Dimension getScaledSize() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(0, 0);
    Image image = getImage();
    if (image != null) {
        double scale = getValue() / 100d;
        size.width = (int) Math.round(image.getWidth(null) * scale);
        size.height = (int) Math.round(image.getHeight(null) * scale);

    }
    return size;
}

public Image getImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

//DefaultZoomModel

```
 package component;

import java.awt.Image;

public class DefaultZoomModel extends AbstractZoomModel {

Image image;

public DefaultZoomModel(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@Override
public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

}
```

//ZoomModel

```
package component;


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.BoundedRangeModel;

public interface ZoomModel extends BoundedRangeModel {

public Image getImage();

public Dimension getScaledSize();

}
```

//ZoomComponent

```
package component;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class ZoomComponent extends JComponent {

private static final String uiClassID = "ZoomComponentUI";
private ZoomModel model;

public ZoomComponent() {
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setFocusable(true);
    updateUI();
}

public void setModel(ZoomModel newModel) {
    if (model != newModel) {
        ZoomModel old = model;
        this.model = newModel;
        firePropertyChange("model", old, newModel);
    }
}

public ZoomModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    ZoomModel model = getModel();
    Dimension size = new Dimension(100, 100);
    if (model != null) {
        size = model.getScaledSize();
    }
    return size;
}


public void setUI(BasicZoomUI ui) {
    super.setUI(ui);
}

@Override
public void updateUI() {
    if (UIManager.get(getUIClassID()) != null) {
        ZoomUI ui = (ZoomUI) UIManager.getUI(this);
        setUI(ui);
    } else {
        setUI(new BasicZoomUI());
    }
}

public BasicZoomUI getUI() {
    return (BasicZoomUI) ui;
}

@Override
public String getUIClassID() {
    return uiClassID;
}
}
```

//BasicZoomUI

package component;

```
public class BasicZoomUI extends ZoomUI {

private ZoomComponent zoomComponent;
private MouseAdapter mouseHandler;
private ChangeListener changeHandler;

private Action zoomIn;
private Action zoomOut;
private PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeHandler;

protected ChangeListener getChangeHandler() {
    if (changeHandler == null) {
        changeHandler = new ChangeHandler();
    }
    return changeHandler;
}

protected void installMouseListener() {
    mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            zoomComponent.requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            int amount = e.getWheelRotation();
            ZoomModel model = zoomComponent.getModel();
            if (model != null) {

                int value = model.getValue();
                model.setValue(value + amount);

            }
        }

    };
    zoomComponent.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
    zoomComponent.addMouseWheelListener(mouseHandler);

}

protected void installModelPropertyChangeListener() {

    propertyChangeHandler = new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            ZoomModel old = (ZoomModel) evt.getOldValue();
            if (old != null) {
                old.removeChangeListener(getChangeHandler());
            }
            ZoomModel newValue = (ZoomModel) evt.getNewValue();
            if (newValue != null) {
                newValue.addChangeListener(getChangeHandler());
            }
        }
    };

    zoomComponent.addPropertyChangeListener("model", propertyChangeHandler);

}

protected void installKeyBindings() {

    zoomIn = new ZoomInAction();
    zoomOut = new ZoomOutAction();

    InputMap inputMap = zoomComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD, 0), "zoomIn");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT, 0), "zoomOut");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, 0), "zoomIn");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS, 0), "zoomOut");

    ActionMap actionMap = zoomComponent.getActionMap();
    actionMap.put("zoomIn", zoomIn);
    actionMap.put("zoomOut", zoomOut);
}

protected void installModelChangeListener() {

    ZoomModel model = getModel();
    if (model != null) {
        model.addChangeListener(getChangeHandler());
    }

}

@Override
public void installUI(JComponent c) {

    zoomComponent = (ZoomComponent) c;

    installMouseListener();
    installModelPropertyChangeListener();
    installKeyBindings();
    installModelChangeListener();

}

protected void uninstallModelChangeListener() {

    getModel().removeChangeListener(getChangeHandler());

}

protected void uninstallKeyBindings() {

    InputMap inputMap = zoomComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD, 0), "donothing");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT, 0), "donothing");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, 0), "donothing");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS, 0), "donothing");

    AbstractAction blank = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    };

    ActionMap actionMap = zoomComponent.getActionMap();
    actionMap.put("zoomIn", blank);
    actionMap.put("zoomOut", blank);

}

protected void uninstallModelPropertyChangeListener() {

    zoomComponent.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeHandler);
    propertyChangeHandler = null;

}

protected void uninstallMouseListener() {

    zoomComponent.removeMouseWheelListener(mouseHandler);
    mouseHandler = null;

}

@Override
public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {

    uninstallModelChangeListener();
    uninstallModelPropertyChangeListener();
    uninstallKeyBindings();
    uninstallMouseListener();

    mouseHandler = null;
    zoomComponent = null;

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    super.paint(g, c);
    paintImage(g);
}

protected void paintImage(Graphics g) {
    if (zoomComponent != null) {
        ZoomModel model = zoomComponent.getModel();
        Image image = model.getImage();
        Dimension size = model.getScaledSize();
        int x = (zoomComponent.getWidth() - size.width) / 2;
        int y = (zoomComponent.getHeight() - size.height) / 2;
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, size.width, size.height, zoomComponent);
    }
}

public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
    return new BasicZoomUI();
}

protected ZoomModel getModel() {

    return zoomComponent == null ? null : zoomComponent.getModel();

}

protected class ChangeHandler implements ChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        zoomComponent.revalidate();
        zoomComponent.repaint();
    }

}

protected class ZoomAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int delta;

    public ZoomAction(int delta) {
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ZoomModel model = getModel();
        if (model != null) {
            model.setValue(model.getValue() + delta);
        }
    }

}

protected class ZoomOutAction extends ZoomAction {

    public ZoomOutAction() {
        super(-5);
    }

}

protected class ZoomInAction extends ZoomAction {

    public ZoomInAction() {
        super(5);
    }

}

}
```

//ZoomUI

```
package component;

import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;

public abstract class ZoomUI extends ComponentUI {    


}
```

This is my test application so far which i Know is incorrect and is not functioning properly whatsoever. Any hints on how I can properly implement this component and getting it running in a test application would be greatly appreaciated

```
package test;


public class ZoomDemo  extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener, ActionListener {

ZoomComponent zoomer;
JPanel board;
private BufferedImage image;

public ZoomDemo( ) {

    super(true);  
    setLayout(new BorderLayout( )); 




    ZoomModel model = new DefaultZoomModel(image);
    board = new JPanel(true); 
    board.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600)); 


    zoomer = new ZoomComponent();
    zoomer.setModel(model);
    add(zoomer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UIManager.getDefaults().put("ZoomComponentUI", "component.BasicZoomUI");
    ZoomDemo s= new ZoomDemo();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample Sketch Application"); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setContentPane(s); 
    frame.pack( ); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: ok I apologize I am new here and made this account specifically for this since I have a deadline to meet